# CDS Runtime Error: Issue changing evaluation date using UpfrontCdsHelper in Python

Tags: programming, quantlib, cds

If I run the below CDS pricing example (from https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/master/Python/examples/cds.py) using the UpfrontCdsHelper instead of the SpreadCdsHelper, I get the following error if I try to rerun for an earlier date relative to the initial date I used (e.g. rerun for May 15, 2006 after running for May 15, 2007):

“RuntimeError: could not notify one or more observers: The cash settlement date must not be before the protection start date.”

For my use case, I have to price multiple CDS over rolling dates and if the evaluation dates on which I price them are not in chronological order then I run into the above issue. The process I’m using to iterate through multiple CDS/dates should be agnostic to the order of dates.

It appears that the crux of the issue is that the helpers are still live with the previously set protection dates when I update the evaluation date to reprice for an earlier date. What exactly is going on and is there a strategic solution/best practice in python to handle this (e.g. clear helpers from memory)? Are there any related implications that I should be aware of when iterating through random permutation of multiple instruments and dates?

Thanks in advance.

```
import QuantLib as ql

calendar = ql.TARGET()

todaysDate = ql.Date(15, ql.May, 2007)#ql.Date(15, ql.May, 2006) #change date to a prior date to recreate issue
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

risk_free_rate = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(todaysDate, 0.01, ql.Actual365Fixed()))

# ### CDS parameters
coupon = 0.01
recovery_rate = 0.5
quoted_spreads = [0.0150, 0.0150, 0.0150, 0.0150]
tenors = [ql.Period(3, ql.Months), ql.Period(6, ql.Months), ql.Period(1, ql.Years), ql.Period(2, ql.Years)]
maturities = [calendar.adjust(todaysDate + x, ql.Following) for x in tenors]

instruments = [
    ql.UpfrontCdsHelper(
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(s)),
        coupon,
        tenor,
        0,
        calendar,
        ql.Quarterly,
        ql.Following,
        ql.DateGeneration.TwentiethIMM,
        ql.Actual365Fixed(),
        recovery_rate,
        risk_free_rate,
    )
    for s, tenor in zip(quoted_spreads, tenors)
]

hazard_curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatHazardRate(todaysDate, instruments, ql.Actual365Fixed())
print("Calibrated hazard rate values: ")
for x in hazard_curve.nodes():
    print("hazard rate on %s is %.7f" % x)

print("Some survival probability values: ")
print(
    "1Y survival probability: %.4g, \n\t\texpected %.4g"
    % (hazard_curve.survivalProbability(todaysDate + ql.Period("1Y")), 0.9704)
)
print(
    "2Y survival probability: %.4g, \n\t\texpected %.4g"
    % (hazard_curve.survivalProbability(todaysDate + ql.Period("2Y")), 0.9418)
)

# ### Reprice instruments

nominal = 1000000.0
probability = ql.DefaultProbabilityTermStructureHandle(hazard_curve)

# We'll create a cds for every maturity:

all_cds = []
for maturity, s in zip(maturities, quoted_spreads):
    schedule = ql.Schedule(
        todaysDate,
        maturity,
        ql.Period(ql.Quarterly),
        calendar,
        ql.Following,
        ql.Unadjusted,
        ql.DateGeneration.TwentiethIMM,
        False,
    )
    cds = ql.CreditDefaultSwap(ql.Protection.Seller, nominal, s, schedule, ql.Following, ql.Actual365Fixed())
    engine = ql.MidPointCdsEngine(probability, recovery_rate, risk_free_rate)
    cds.setPricingEngine(engine)
    all_cds.append(cds)

print("Repricing of quoted CDSs employed for calibration: ")
for cds, tenor in zip(all_cds, tenors):
    print("%s fair spread: %.7g" % (tenor, cds.fairSpread()))
    print("   NPV: %g" % cds.NPV())
    print("   default leg: %.7g" % cds.defaultLegNPV())
    print("   coupon leg: %.7g" % cds.couponLegNPV())
    print("")
    
#updating evaluation date fails
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate - ql.Period(12, ql.Months)
```

Comment: As of QuantLib 1.31, this was fixed (see https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/pull/1704).  Thanks for reporting the problem.